# UICollectionview with specific number of columns and rows using swift

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, multiple-columns, rows

I want to implement the following using **Swift3**, but I don't know the best approach to do so.

[image]

I tried collection view but couldn't figure out how to use specific number of columns and rows in collectionView. I tried using customLayout with collectionView but didn't get anywhere.

Any help please, Thanks

Here's my last version of code result is all items are shown in one row and collection view scrolls horizontally.
and a side note, my collectionView is already inside tableviewCell.

```
extension QuestionsHomeVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let itemIndex = collectionView.tag;
    let answers = pageData.questionItems[itemIndex].answers;
    let coloums = answers.filter{$0["questionDetailType"] as! Int == 2 };
    return coloums.count + 1
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    let itemIndex = collectionView.tag;
    let answers = pageData.questionItems[itemIndex].answers;
    let rows = answers.filter{$0["questionDetailType"] as! Int == 1 };
    return rows.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if(indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0){
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderMatrixCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderMatrixCell
        cell.lbl.text = "";
        return cell;
    }else{
        if(indexPath.section == 0){
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderMatrixCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderMatrixCell
            let itemIndex = collectionView.tag;
            let answers = pageData.questionItems[itemIndex].answers;
            let coloums = answers.filter{$0["questionDetailType"] as! Int == 2 };
            if !(coloums[indexPath.row - 1]["title"] is NSNull) {
                cell.lbl.text = coloums[indexPath.row - 1]["title"] as! String?
            }
            cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray;
            return cell;
        }else{
            if(indexPath.row == 0){
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderMatrixCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderMatrixCell
                let itemIndex = collectionView.tag;
                let answers = pageData.questionItems[itemIndex].answers;
                let rows = answers.filter{$0["questionDetailType"] as! Int == 1 };
                if !(rows[indexPath.row]["title"] is NSNull) {
                    cell.lbl.text = rows[indexPath.row]["title"] as! String?
                }
                cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray;
                return cell;
            }else{
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BodyItemMatrixCell", for: indexPath) as! BodyItemMatrixCell
                return cell;
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Please show your code and point exactly at that point where you have problems. If you don't have code, search the internet and read.

Comment: for now it's the setup code for collection view, with implementation of Datasource and DataDelegate nothing more, I tried to use mutli sections as rows but the result was different. "the sections are denoted as row and the rows as columns, so keep this in mind to set the number of sections and items" I read it in some tutorial so I used it as a start point. but as I said the result was not what I wanted.

Comment: Also you can use collectionView inside a tableView. each tableViewCell will contain a collectionView.

Comment: Unless you show some code the chances of this question being answered are low.  There are multiple ways to achieve it.  You could us a UICollectionView with a custom layout.  You could use a UITableView with fixed views inside it perhaps using a UIStackView.  You could use a UITableView with a UICollectionView inside it.  The method used will depend on your exact requirements.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question, thanks.